# "in the night of" VS "On the night of"

Tags: prepositions

1. **In** the night of 22 to 23 August 1791, men and women, torn from Africa and sold into slavery, revolted against  the slave system to obtain freedom and independence for Haiti, gained in 1804.
2. **On** the night of 22 to 23 August 1791, men and women, torn from Africa and sold into slavery, revolted against  the slave system to obtain freedom and independence for Haiti, gained in 1804.

Which one is suitable?

Comment: What is the source and when written? I wonder if it is dated or strictly literary usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On the night** is correct in this context. It's a way of referring back to some recent or historical action that took place on (or commenced on) a certain night.

In a court case, lawyers would refer to such an action as having occurred **on the night** of the date concerned.

**In the night** is used more loosely, often in songs, poems, novels and the like to refer to the period of darkness and all that people associate with it.

> In the night ghouls and ghosties are about.
>
> In the night owls can be heard calling across the valley.

There is also the more prosaic **at night**, used to refer to night time activities.

> My shifts involve work at night.
>
> The shop remains open at night.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121858/at-night-or-in-the-night

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-say-in-the-morning-but-not-in-the-night